# Sorry, Ubuntu 18.04 has experienced an internal error (UI is not update to 18.04)

Tags: upgrade

Here are screenshots of error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Its hows that its is updated to 18.04 but the UI is of 16.04

Comment: its shows it is upgraded to 18.04 but all UI is of 16.04

Comment: The UI you are probably talking about is Unity.  It can be used still on 18.04 LTS; you can probably logout and switch to GNOME if that's what you prefer (look for a gear or cog to switch on the login/greeter screen).

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to reflect your question.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the meta-package for unity changed to `ubuntu-unity-desktop` It's moved to universe. `ubuntu-desktop` Meta package points now to gnome3

If you really have both on your System decide which desktop you want. Both together is not a smart idea. They have influence among one another. 
check it first.

```
dpkg -l | egrep 'unity|gnome'
```

For removing unity `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-unity-desktop unity`
 and to install the right meta-package `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

---

For remove gnome3 `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell` and `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-unity-desktop`

Comment: Please can you except the answer? This is the 3. time I read your post because I thought it is not solved.

Comment: my issue is solved